Window postMessage is not working on IOS and Android Browsers
I'm using Nextjs and on my laptop the code is working as intended
when accessing the page from my Iphone it didn't load
I'm using it to send data between iframes on two different sites
on the Nextjs project
useEffect(() => {
const handleLoad = () => {
  if (iframeRef.current) {
    iframeRef.current.contentWindow.postMessage(
      { data },
      process.env.IFRAME_LINK
    );
  }
};

if (iframeRef.current) {
  iframeRef.current.addEventListener('load', handleLoad);
}

return () => {
  if (iframeRef.current) {
    iframeRef.current.removeEventListener('load', handleLoad);
  }
};
}, [iframeRef.current]);

Again on a pc/laptop this working
The Iframe site code (Vite React)
useEffect(() => {
const handleMessage = (event) => {
  const parentURL = import.meta.env.PARENT_URL;
  if (event.origin !== parentURL) return;
  let { data } = event.data;
  console.log('received');
  setUserData(data);
};

window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);
return () => {
  window.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage);
};
}, []);


is the iframe site at least loaded in the iframe? if not, did you load it in https?

it is loading but to work properly it waits for data from the original one (which on laptop/pc works perfectly) on mobile it doesn't send it/other site doesn't receive it

setTimeout solved it
useEffect(() => {
    if (iframeRef.current) {
      iframeRef.current.onload = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          iframeRef.current.contentWindow.postMessage(
            { data  }
          ,process.env.IFRAME_LINK);
        }, 100);
      };
    }
  }, []);


I tried the same just a change I did is
if (iframeRef.current) {
  iframeRef.current.addEventListener('loadeddata', handleLoad);
}

I Used loadmetadata instead if load and instead of using import.meta.env.PARENT_URL; I used a static url.
You can console or put an alert before your if (event.origin !== parentURL) return;
for parent url it might be stuck there.
Initially it happend with me as well.

The issue with the env variable might be due to the fact that Vite requires env variables in a .env file to be prepended by VITE_.

@moonstar-x Yes it can be one of them

This could be due to one of the reasons below:

Cross-Origin Restrictions: Mobile browsers can be stricter. Ensure process.env.IFRAME_LINK and import.meta.env.PARENT_URL are correct and match the exact origin (https://your-domain.com)
iframe Loading: The iframe might not be fully loaded when postMessage is sent.
Safari Quirks: Mobile Safari sometimes needs extra handling for event listeners and postMessage.

Ensure the iframe is loaded before sending the message in the parent (next.js):
useEffect(() => {
  const handleLoad = () => {
    iframeRef.current?.contentWindow?.postMessage({ data }, 'https://your-iframe-site.com');
  };

  iframeRef.current?.addEventListener('load', handleLoad);

  return () => iframeRef.current?.removeEventListener('load', handleLoad);
}, [iframeRef]);

iframe (Vite React):
Check the message origin to allow only trusted sources:
useEffect(() => {
  const handleMessage = (event) => {
    if (event.origin !== 'https://your-parent-site.com') return;
    setUserData(event.data?.data);
  };

  window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage);
}, []);

Additional Tips:

Test with hardcoded origins (replace environment variables temporarily).

Add a slight delay in postMessage for Safari:
setTimeout(() => iframeRef.current?.contentWindow?.postMessage({ data }, 'https://your-iframe-site.com'), 100);


